# Wave shape function

Tags: audio

We have 3 hours of audio, each instant of which contains either one of two people talking or silence. We need to determine which of these options each moment corresponds to using hmm.

To that end, what are some not-insanely-difficult functions that will give different outputs when wave shapes are different (sine, saw, square, etc.) but the same answer for different volumes, pitches, etc.

Is this project doable?

Comment: Identifying simple waveforms like sine and square is a completely different solution that human speech. What is the connection you are trying to make between the two?

Comment: We were thinking quality or timbre is related to wave shape, which might in turn hint at the speaker. If that was an incorrect assumption, what would be the simplest features of the sound wave that are correlated to the speaker? I know there are libraries that will do the whole thing, but are there ways to do it ourselves that are not prohibitively difficult? The results don't have to be 100% accurate. An approximation will suffice.

Comment: You might look into using the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), which will basically give you frequency vs. amplitude for the input audio. Since every sound wave is comprised of many frequencies, the FFT will tell you the "shape" of the wave. It will vary depending on what vowel/consonant each person is saying, but with some filtering and an an HMM or Random Decision Forest classifier you _may_ be able to identify a speaker.